# cgo bug : No such file or directory #cgo LDFLAGS: -lpam -fPIC

Tags: go, cgo, pam

i am trying to build a go project that uses #cgo and i keep running into the same problem :

```
./pam.go:36:10: fatal error: security/pam_appl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <security/pam_appl.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

here is the project https://github.com/uber/pam-ussh. i just added some lines of code for my own use nothing to complicated just a http request. since i read in an issue it might be from go version i am mentioning it is 1.14.1.
and here is the error using make file

```
/tmp/go-build094518109/b053/pam.cover.go:36:10: fatal error: security/pam_appl.h: No such file or directory
 #cgo LDFLAGS: -lpam -fPIC
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~     
compilation terminated.
```

so after installing libpam0g-dev i get the new error

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpam.so when searching for -lpam
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpam.a when searching for -lpam
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpam
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

my system :

```
Linux span-ThinkPad-T490 4.15.0-109-generic #110-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 23 02:39:32 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

go version

```
go version go1.14.4 linux/386
```

Comment: Do you have `libpam0g-dev` installed?

Comment: You are likely attempting to build a 32 bit binary. What system are you on (`uname -a`), which go toolchain do you have (`go version`), how are you building it (command line), and what are your `GOOS` and `GOARCH`?

Comment: i have not set GOOS or  GOARCH. 
and added other informations to the question @Marc

Comment: You're using a 32 bit Go toolchain. Switch to `go1.14.4.linux-amd64`